# How to get the id from programmatically linear layout item

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-linearlayout

I don't know how to get the id of an item in a programmatically created linear layout. I want to "catch" the right id of a button and associate that with fields.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.content_doodle_linearlayout3);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  


    String[] data = {"1","2","3","4"};
    String[] users = {"1","2","3"};


 for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        text = new TextView(this);
        text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text.setText("Name " + (i));
        text.setId(1000 + i);

        row.addView(text);
        int ergebnis = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < daten.length; j++) {
            CheckBox btnTag = new CheckBox(this);
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            //btnTag.setText("Button " + (j + 1 + (i * 4)));
            btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));

            row.addView(btnTag);
        }

        layout.addView(row);
    }
```

The Buttons can't not be found, because there "isn't" a (R.id.{XML-Field}).

How can i "find" the clicked button from the specific row. Do i have to code every button?

Comment: you can do this by settag and then retrieve the values by getTag method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a specified tag for each child view in your layout in this way:

```
View childView = ...;
childView.setTag("Some tag");
```

And then in your onClickListener:

```
child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Object tag = view.getTag();
        if (tag instanceof String) {
            String stringTag = (String) tag;
            if (stringTag.equals("Some tag") {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not understand the first line View childview. Can you explain that? And Isn't it the same behavior just in another place?

Comment: childView is your btnTag. So just set tag instead of id: btnTag.setTag(j + 1 + (i * 4));

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps. maybe i have to make a listview, recyclerview or gridlayout with some adapter to solve my problems.

Comment: Yes, because you may have a lot of users, it's better to use RecyclerView due to memory issues. Then you can get items by list positons.